# Matlab's gamultiobj plots

Tags: plot, genetic-algorithm, matlab

In matlab's multiobjective genetic algorithm GUI there is an option for plotting the pareto front but the plot is only 2D; since i'm minimizing three objective functions, i need a 3D plot. Is there a way to force the 2D plot to 3D or must I plot using a custom function?

Comment: Matlab does do 3d graphs, just make sure you are graphing a 3D matrix and all should be ok. _ not a real answer as i dont know _how_ to do it Off the top of my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,my bad; the plot was really a 3D one but the plot initially pops up as a seemingly 2D one, since its rotated. To see the plot in 3D , just click the "rotate" toolbar button and click and drag the plot a little so that the 3 axes are visible.